# chrome devtools doesn't show correct width

Tags: html, css, web

I've been trying to create a responsive page so I wanted it to act differently in mobile browsers so I added some @media codes and realized that it doesn't work and I found out that the width that I'm giving to the page -in responsive mode in chrome devtools - isn't the width that the page has. I read my code over and over and coudn't find what's wrong with it.
[2 widths doesn't match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SObyx.png)

Comment: Please do supply us with some code, not ur localhost

Comment: just enter the address in the address bar bro...! it's not localhost...!

Comment: What is is you want it to do? Your media queries work fine on the widths you defined. [Screenshot here](https://i.imgur.com/Rl59CfF.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask], and [mcve]. Code relevant to your question belongs directly _into_ your question. // Guess in this instance though would be that you probably want to familiarize yourself with the `viewport` meta property.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add the tag to make it responsive:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: you didn't understand the question properly.I'm not looking for @media queries. I already have those. it's just that it doesn't work!

Comment: You forgot to add the metatag to make it responsive

Comment: I love you man,I love you!

Comment: this doesn't fix the issue directly. if you *change* the scale and then change it back, it forces chrome to update with the correct scaling and dimensions in the dev tools mobile view.